# В следствии чего возникает ошибка с if?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет, можете пожалуйста подсказать из-за чего появляется ошибка:

```
  File "----", line 17
    if a < now < b:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Вот часть кода:

```py
bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)    

now = datetime.now().time()
a = datetime.strptime('10:00', '%H:%M').time()
b = datetime.strptime('20:00', '%H:%M').time()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])

if a < now < b:
    def welcome(message):
    sti = open('hello.tgs', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "----".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), parse_mode='html')

    #city
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard = True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("1")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("2")

    markup.add(item1, item2)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "----?", reply_markup = markup)
else:
    @bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
    def closed(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "----".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()),parse_mode = 'html')
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: У вас выше этой строчки идет декоратор `@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])`, он может применяться к функциям. Таким образом интетпретатор ждет, что после него будет функция, а там идет кот и это неверно. Попробуйте после строчки с `@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])` сделать функцию, как это сделано у вас в блоке `else` в конце примера

Comment: и код правильно напечатайте тут.

Comment: я добавил def worktime(): а под ней поставил if, но он продолжает ругаться: TypeError: worktime() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given